# React Native - ScrollView with sticky button at the bottom

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I want to scroll the view and have a sticky button at the bottom always.

So the requirement are:

1. `ScrollView` with items.
2. Fixed button overlaps scroll view at
   the bottom position
3. Scroll the view and the button need to be
   always at bottom of the screen.
4. The sticky button are always
   visible

This is my code:

```
        <ScrollView >
                <TouchableOpacity s>
                    <Image source={..)} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Image source={..)} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Image source={..)} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.fabMenuStyle}>
              <Image source={..)} />
              <Image source={..)} />
              <Image source={..)} />
            </View>

fabMenuStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 5,
    justifyContent: 'center'
}
```

The problem is that I can position my buttons view at the bottom of the `ScrollView`, but I need that to always be visible at the bottom, not only at the end of the `ScrollView`.